# Draw raw array of pixels onto a window (C++ WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, buffer, drawing

I have two buffers, both of the same size and type (`uint32_t*`).
These buffers are supposed to represent the front and back buffers of a rendering/drawing system. They store 32-bit pixel data.

I declare and initialize these buffers using;

```cpp
private:
    ...
    uint32_t* frontBuf;
    uint32_t* backBuf;
    size_t    gbufSize;
    ...
public:
    void Initialize() {
        ...  
        // prepare for rendering
        gbufSize = sizeof(uint32_t) * w * h;
        backBuf  = (uint32_t*)malloc(gbufSize);
        frontBuf = (uint32_t*)malloc(gbufSize);
        ...
    }
```

I also get the output, window and device handles for the console in the `Initialize()` method using:

```cpp
        // get handles
        cwd = GetDC(GetConsoleWindow());
        chd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        cwn = GetConsoleWindow();
```

I then have a few drawing methods, like a `SetPixel` method:

```cpp
    size_t GFlatten(int x, int y) {
        return y * h + x;
    }

    void GSetPixel(int x, int y, uint32_t color) {
        backBuf[GFlatten(x, y)] = color;
    }
```

And finally, I have a `GSwap` method. This method is supposed to swap the pointers of the buffers, clear the new back buffer and copy the front buffer to the screen.

**The first two work (I think), but I have no idea how to implement the 3rd one (copying to the screen). I would prefer to not use any external libraries.**

***Code for `GSwap` method:***

```cpp
    void GSwap() {
        // swap pointers
        uint32_t* frontTmp = frontBuf;
        frontBuf = backBuf;
        backBuf = frontTmp;

        // clear new back buffer
        memset(backBuf, 0, gbufSize);

        // draw on screen
        /* ??? */
    }
```

**The full code: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/AMHvCTeK)**

Comment: To render onto a window, you need to be the owner of that window. The window handle returned by `GetConsoleWindow()` is not that window. Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) if you are confident that you do not need a book. Get Petzold's [Programming Windows](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't draw to an arbitrary window by poking bytes into some buffer. Win32 is a higher level API than that.

It is possible to draw *into a bitmap* by writing into a buffer, however. You create a bitmap such that Windows returns a pointer to its contents when you create it with [`CreateDIBSection(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection). You can then paint that bitmap to a Window via `BitBlt` and appropriate device contexts, etc.

Below is a minimal example. (I retained your usage of a back buffer and front buffer even though it isn't really necessary here. The window itself is essentially a front buffer so you would only really need "a swap chain" of one back buffer to not have flickering.)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr int kTimerID = 101;

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

struct graphics_buffer {
    HBITMAP hbm;
    uint32_t* data;
};

graphics_buffer create_graphics_buffer(int wd, int hgt)
{
    HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);

    BITMAPINFO bmi = {};
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = wd;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -hgt; // top-down
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    graphics_buffer gb;
    gb.hbm = CreateDIBSection(hdcScreen, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&gb.data), NULL, NULL);

    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
    return gb;
}

class graphic_buffers {
    graphics_buffer front_;
    graphics_buffer back_;
    int wd_; 
    int hgt_;

public:

    graphic_buffers(int wd, int hgt) :
        wd_(wd),
        hgt_(hgt),
        front_(create_graphics_buffer(wd, hgt)),
        back_(create_graphics_buffer(wd, hgt))
    {
        clear();
    }

    HBITMAP front_bmp() {
        return front_.hbm;
    }

    void swap() {
        std::swap(front_, back_);
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return static_cast<size_t>(wd_ * hgt_);
    }

    int width() const {
        return wd_;
    }

    int height() const {
        return hgt_;
    }

    void clear() {
        std::fill(back_.data, back_.data + size(), 0);
    }

    void set_pixel(int x, int y, uint32_t pix) {
        back_.data[y * wd_ + x] = pix;
    }

    ~graphic_buffers() {
        DeleteObject(front_.hbm);
        DeleteObject(back_.hbm);
    }
};

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"swap_buffers_window";
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return 1;

    if (!CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName,
        L"buffered window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, hInstance, NULL))
        return 2;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

void draw_something(graphic_buffers& buffs) {
    int wd = buffs.width();
    int hgt = buffs.height();

    static int x = 0;
    static int y = 0;
    static int x_vel = 4;
    static int y_vel = 7;

    if (x >= 0 && x < wd && y >= 0 && y < hgt) {
        buffs.set_pixel(x, y, 0xffffffff);
    }

    x += x_vel;
    y += y_vel;
    if (x < 0 || x > wd) {
        x_vel *= -1;
    }
    if (y < 0 || y > hgt) {
        y_vel *= -1;
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: {
            RECT r;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);
            SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(new graphic_buffers(r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top)));
            SetTimer(hWnd, kTimerID, 1, NULL);
        }
        break;
    case WM_TIMER: {
            auto buffs = reinterpret_cast<graphic_buffers*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
            draw_something(*buffs);
            buffs->swap();
            buffs->clear();
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT: {
            auto buffs = reinterpret_cast<graphic_buffers*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            HDC hdc_bmp = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            auto old_bmp = SelectObject(hdc_bmp, buffs->front_bmp());

            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, buffs->width(), buffs->height(), hdc_bmp, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            SelectObject(hdc, old_bmp);
            DeleteDC(hdc_bmp);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY: {
            auto buffs = reinterpret_cast<graphic_buffers*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
            delete buffs;
        }
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```